# How can I prove the IFF condition for this group of matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm tasked with showing that matrix $A$ commutes with every $2\times2$ matrix **if and only if** $A = \begin{bmatrix}a & 0\\0 & a\end{bmatrix}$ for some a.

I was able to prove in the first direction, assuming that $A = \begin{bmatrix}a & 0\\0 & a\end{bmatrix}$, by just multiplying the matrix by $\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\c & d\end{bmatrix}$ in AB = BA format, and showing how AB does equal BA.

$$ (=>)$$

$$\begin{bmatrix}a & 0\\0 & a\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\c & d\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}a & b\\c & d\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a & 0\\0 & a\end{bmatrix}$$

$$\begin{bmatrix}a^2 & ab\\ac & ad\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}a^2 & ab\\ac & ad\end{bmatrix}$$

But now I have to prove in the other direction, assuming that A already does commute with every $2\times 2$ matrix, and I'm not particularly sure how I can do that. Somehow, I have to show that if A commutes with $\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\c & d\end{bmatrix}$, then A will be $\begin{bmatrix}a & 0\\0 & a\end{bmatrix}$, and I don't know how I can carry that out.

Where can I start? Ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Your proof of the first direction is flawed, since choosing the same variable name $a$ in both matrices causes Loss Of Generality. With different names the argument is not really harder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the elementary matrices:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix},\quad
\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix},\quad
\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\\1 & 0\end{bmatrix},\quad
\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\\0 & 1\end{bmatrix}
$$
What do you get when you force $A$ to commute with each of them?

Comment: In fact, a matrix commutes with every matrix iff it commutes with the elementary matrices, because the  elementary matrices form a basis for the space of  matrices.

Answer (score 1):

For the opposite direction, it helps to write down the fact that you matrix commutes with *particular* matrices, which you can choose as simple as you like, so that the computations won't be too hard. With a few good choices you may get to your goal, as you need to establish only $3$ equations in the $4$ unknowns $a,b,c,d$ (namely $a=d$, $b=0$, and $c=0$). You might find a very small set of matrices such that any matrix commuting with *them* automatically commutes with *everyone* (because the former condition forces them to be of the form $$
\begin{pmatrix}a&0\\0&a\end{pmatrix}$$). Your particluar matrix should of course not be so simple as to be the null matrix, or more generally a multiple of the identity matrix, since you know that those commute with everyone, so the won't give you any useful equations. But there are some very simple choices left.